# SEDE footer still says "stack overflow internet services, inc"

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, copyright, footer

The footer of most Stack Exchange sites was changed to show "stack exchange inc" as a result of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82744/footer-is-wrong. However, the Data Explorer's footer has not yet been updated.

Comment: @Nemo: The [tag:company] tag has nothing substantive to do with this 9-year old bug report. Please don't bump posts in this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fixed in source](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=34d59e3f4666620396c64fff15ccc038a546e107).

Thanks for finding this.

Comment: This is now live.